# Can't render twitter stream in Github Pages

Tags: github, twitter, jekyll, github-pages

I set up the twitter stream from [here](https://github.com/rob-murray/jekyll-twitter-plugin) and got it to work on localhost, but Github Pages isn't rendering it.

[This](http://keitaito.com/blog/2017/01/20/embedding-tweets-in-github-pages.html) page says that all Pages sites are generated using the `--safe` option to disable custom plugins for security reasons, which means the twitter stream won't show up on Github Pages.

Can anybody think of an alternative?

[This](https://abhisheknaik96.github.io/AllPosts) is the page and its [source](http://github.com/abhisheknaik96/abhisheknaik96.github.io/).

Answer (score 1):

Github pages simply has its own list of plugins they support and `jekyll-twitter-plugin` is not one of them. For complete list check [this link](https://pages.github.com/versions/)

Comment: Yes, but what do you suggest as an alternative?

Comment: Build it on your own, twitter feeds are easily customizable via https://publish.twitter.com/

Answer (score 1):

Side note before starting in on the following, it probably be a good idea to grab a snack an drink...

---

> > Github pages simply has its own list of plugins they support and jekyll-twitter-plugin is not one of them.
> >     -- Mario Nikolaus

While technically correct in that plugins loaded from **`Gemfile`** and **`_config.yml`** files are restricted, GitHub Pages does support submodules so long **`https`** URLs are used for tracking such things.

Or in other-words, if the problem to be solved can be expressed with Liquid and/or S(C|A)SS, a little coxing of GitHub Pages can encourage loading of code from elsewhere automatically.

> > Can anybody think of an alternative?
> >     -- anaik

Yes, and it works with GitHub Pages see [live demo](https://liquid-utilities.github.io/twitter-timeline/) for examples and the [source](https://github.com/liquid-utilities/twitter-timeline) for how to utilize within other repositories. What follows be paraphrased from the *quick start*.

---

Change current working directory to a repository and checkout your `gh-pages` branch

```
cd ~/git/hub/your-project
git checkout gh-pages
```

Make a `modules` directory under the `_includes` subdirectory and initialize the previously linked repository as a new submodule

```
mkdir -p _includes/modules

git submodule add\
 -b master --name 'twitter-timeline'\
 'https://github.com/liquid-utilities/twitter-timeline.git'\
 '_includes/modules/twitter-timeline'
```

Edit a site layout file to include the Liquid *plugin*, in this case I'm using Minima 2.5.0; hint, version can be found within `Gemfile.lock` file if not listed anywhere else.

**`_layouts/default.html`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ page.lang | default: site.lang | default: "en" }}">

  {%- include head.html -%}

  <body>

    {%- include header.html -%}

    <main class="page-content" aria-label="Content">
      <div class="wrapper">
        {{ content }}
        {% if page.twitter-timeline %}
          {% include modules/twitter-timeline/twitter-timeline.html %}
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    </main>

    {%- include footer.html -%}

  </body>

</html>
{% comment %}
  Source: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jekyll/minima/v2.5.0/_layouts/default.html
  License: MIT
{% endcomment %}
```

> Note, the main edits to the original theme where...

```
{% if page.twitter-timeline %}
  {% include modules/twitter-timeline/twitter-timeline.html %}
{% endif %}
```

> ... and one may also have to *fiddle* with placement and CSS to get things *meshing* nicely.

Edit post or page FrontMatter to trigger Liquid *plugin*

**`2019-07-15-timeline.md`**

```
---
layout: post
title: "Example Twitter Timeline"
date: 2019-07-15 13:58:05 -0700
categories: twitter timelines
twitter-timeline:
  name: TwitterDev
  width: 300
  height: 300
  chrome: nofooter noscrollbar noborders transparent
  tweet_limit: 3
  inject_js: true
---


Whatever content to be placed before _injection_ of Twitter Timeline
```

Add and commit changes, then push to GitHub for testing...

```
git add .gitmodules
git add _includes/modules/twitter-timeline
git add _layouts/default.html
git add _posts/2019-07-15-timeline.md


git commit -F- <<'EOF'
:heavy_plus_sign: Adds liquid-utilities/twitter-timeline submodule

# Add anything else of note, though do be aware that lines
# that begin with `#` are ignored with this _fanciness_
EOF


git push origin gh-pages
```

> URL will be something like *`https://` **`your-name-or-organization`** `.github.io/` **`your-project`** `/twitter/timelines/2019/07/15/timeline.html`* if using the above FrontMatter with the Minima theme.

---

Now that may seem like a *bit much* for something trying to pass itself off as a *plugin*, but here's where the *gains* are.

- To update/upgrade submodules use something like...

```
git submodule update --init --merge --remote --recursive
```

- To add another Twitter Timeline to another post...

```
---
layout: post
title: "Example Twitter Collection Timeline"
date: 2019-07-17 13:58:05 -0700
categories: twitter examples
twitter-timeline:
  name: TwitterDev
  text: National Park Tweets
  type: collection
  collection: 539487832448843776
  chrome: nofooter noscrollbar noborders transparent
  tweet_limit: 3
  inject_js: true
---


> Something noteworthy about parks, maybe...
```

- To add to another project utilize the previous instructions
- While it doesn't do everything the Gem plugin does it at least show how to *offload* similar features into reusable *chunks*

So aside from initializing/installation, submodules operate similarly to any other *plugin*, and such things **don't** require any Continuous Integration workarounds among other *benefits*.

> Note, if ya ever get a submodule with a `detached HEAD`, change working directories to the submodule and `fetch`/`pull` the `master` branch.
>
> Hint, check out [DependaBot](https://github.com/marketplace/dependabot-preview) if ya ever want a bot to automatically suggest pull requests when a submodule has updates.

If there's anything questionably about what's suggested above please comment so that the answer may be improved, if bugs are found with how the linked to repository utilizes the Twitter API then please either open an Issue or Pull Request on GitHub so that the code doesn't annoy server administrators.